# How can I get current month as number ie. "1" in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I get current month not as "Jan" but I want it in this format `"1"`, in short I want current month `as number` because I want to append that number into string to complete URL Link for JSON Parsing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Try this you will get month number

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFor = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFor setDateFormat:@"MM"];
//[dateFor setDateFormat:@"M"]; // Use single M for avoid 0 before month number
NSString *monthNumber = [dateFor stringFromDate:date];
```

Hope it will help..

Comment: Thank You @Jogendra.Com this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar) to get [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents?language=objc) from it:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

NSInteger month = [components month];
```